# Can someone please tell me why my winning conditions aren't working?

Tags: java

I'm making the game connect four however whenever I run the program, it drops the circles and everything but the winning conditions do not work. I'm not too sure if I'm calling to them not correctly or if it's just not being called to in the right spots. Please advise. I appreciate your upcoming answers.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ConnectFourJan {

  static boolean winCheck; 
  static drawBoard drawConnectFourBoard = new drawBoard();
  static int [][] spotOnBoard = new int [6][7];
  static int maxRow=6;
  static int maxCol=7;
  static boolean endOfGame = false;
  static boolean gameStart;
  static JPanel boardPanel;

  static JButton firstOption = new JButton ("Drop");
  static JButton secondOption = new JButton ("Drop");
  static JButton thirdOption = new JButton ("Drop");
  static JButton fourthOption = new JButton ("Drop");
  static JButton fifthOption = new JButton ("Drop");
  static JButton sixthOption = new JButton ("Drop");
  static JButton seventhOption = new JButton ("Drop");

  static JButton playAgain = new JButton ("New");
  static JButton reset = new JButton ("Reset");
  static JButton exit = new JButton ("Exit");

  static int blank =0;
  static int red=1;
  static int yellow=2;
  static int firstColour= red;

  public static void board() {
    spotOnBoard = new int [maxRow][maxCol];
    for (int row=0; row < maxRow; row++){
      for (int col=0; col< maxCol; col++){
        spotOnBoard[row][col]=blank;
      }
    }
  }  

  public static class drawBoard extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
      super.paintComponent(g);
      drawConnectFourBoard(g); 
    }//end of paintComponent.

    void drawConnectFourBoard(Graphics g){          
      g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, 100+100*maxCol, 100+100*maxRow);
      for (int row=0; row<maxRow; row++)
        for (int col=0; col<maxCol; col++) {
        if (spotOnBoard[row][col]==blank) g.setColor(Color.white);
        if (spotOnBoard[row][col]==red) g.setColor(Color.red);
        if (spotOnBoard[row][col]==yellow) g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillOval(100*col, 100*row, 100, 100);
      }
    }
  }

  public static boolean winCheck(int colour) { 
   int box;
    if (colour==red)
      box = red;
    else
      box = yellow;
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) { 
      for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) { 
        if(spotOnBoard[j][k]==(box)) {           
          if(((j -3) >= 0) && spotOnBoard[j -1][k]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j -2][k]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j -3][k]==(box)) {  
            return true;
          }          
          else if(((k -3) >= 0) && spotOnBoard[j][k -1]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j][k -2]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j][k -3]==(box)) {
            return true; 
          }          
          else if(((j+3)<= 5) && spotOnBoard[j+1][k]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j+2][k]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j+3][k]==(box)){ 
            return true;
          }          
          else if(((k +3) <= 6) && spotOnBoard[j][k +1]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j][k +2]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j][k +3]==(box)) {          
            return true; 
          }          
          else if(((j -3)>= 0) && ((k +3)<=6) && spotOnBoard[j-1][k+1]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j-2][k+2]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j-3][k+3]==(box)){ 
            return true; 
          }          
          else if(((j +3) <=5) && ((k -3) >=0) && spotOnBoard[j +1][k -1]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j +2][k -2]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j +3][k -3]==(box)){ 
            return true;
          }          
          else if(((j -3)>=0) && ((k -3)>= 0) && spotOnBoard[j -1][k -1]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j -2][k -2]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j -3][k -3]==(box)){ 
            return true;
          }          
          else if(((j +3) <=5) && ((k +3) <=6) && spotOnBoard[j +1][k +1]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j +2][k +2]==(box) && spotOnBoard[j +3][k +3]==(box)){
            return true; 
          }

        }
      } 
    }
    return false; 
  }

  public static void displayWinner(int n) {
    if (n==red) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "red wins! Congratulations!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
    }
    else
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yellow wins! Congratulations!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
  }

  public static void main (String [] args) {
    board();
    ButtonHandler listen = new ButtonHandler();

    firstOption.addActionListener(listen);
    secondOption.addActionListener(listen);
    thirdOption.addActionListener(listen);
    fourthOption.addActionListener(listen);
    fifthOption.addActionListener(listen);
    sixthOption.addActionListener(listen);
    seventhOption.addActionListener(listen);
    playAgain.addActionListener(listen);
    reset.addActionListener(listen);
    exit.addActionListener(listen);

    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,7));   
    topPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
    topPanel.add(firstOption);
    topPanel.add(secondOption);
    topPanel.add(thirdOption);
    topPanel.add(fourthOption);
    topPanel.add(fifthOption);
    topPanel.add(sixthOption);
    topPanel.add(seventhOption);    

    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
    bottomPanel.add(playAgain);
    bottomPanel.add(reset);
    bottomPanel.add(exit);    

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,214,154));
    mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(drawConnectFourBoard);
    board();
    mainPanel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JFrame window = new JFrame ("Connect4");
    window.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    window.setSize(720,700);
    window.setLocation(500,100);
    window.setResizable(true);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }

   private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
      if (a.getSource()== firstOption)
        dropCircle(0);      
      else if (a.getSource()== secondOption)
        dropCircle(1);
      else if (a.getSource()== thirdOption)
        dropCircle(2);
      else if (a.getSource()== fourthOption)
        dropCircle(3);
      else if (a.getSource()== fifthOption)
        dropCircle(4);
      else if (a.getSource()== sixthOption)
        dropCircle(5);
      else if (a.getSource()==seventhOption)
        dropCircle(6);

    if (a.getSource() == playAgain) {
      gameStart=true;
    }
    if (a.getSource() == exit) {
      System.exit(0);
    }
    if (a.getSource() == reset) {
      for (int row=0; row < maxRow; row++){
        for (int col=0; col< maxCol; col++){
          spotOnBoard[row][col]=blank;
        }
      }
      drawConnectFourBoard.repaint();
    }
    }

    public void dropCircle(int n) {
      if (endOfGame) return;
      gameStart=true;
      int row;
      for (row=0; row<maxRow; row++)
       if (spotOnBoard[row][n]>0) break;
      if (row>0) {
        if(winCheck(firstColour)){
          displayWinner(firstColour);
        }
        spotOnBoard[--row][n]=firstColour;
        if (firstColour==red)
          firstColour=yellow;
        else
          firstColour=red;        
      }
      drawConnectFourBoard.repaint();
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: A debugger could tell you.

Comment: Don't compare String values using `==`. Use `equals()`.

Comment: I had .equals before but because I'm using int's everywhere else I decided to continue it with ==.

Comment: `String [][] spotOnBoard` <= doesn't look like ints to me.

Comment: You decided to compare strings incorrectly because you're also comparing ints in lots of places?

Comment: But whenever I had .equals() it was the same as == whenever I ran the program. It has to be the fact that I called to it wrong someplace.

Comment: @user3216679 "asd" == "asdd" is far from equivalent of "asd".equals("asdd"). The first checks if the two Strings are one and the same object and the other actually compares their contents (the letters of the Strings). That is VERY basic Java stuff.

Comment: Please review revised. It still doesn't work... The winning conditions do not work.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that in `dropCircle`, you're populating `boardArray`, but in `winCheck`, when you're checking for a win, you're looking in `spotOnBoard`, which is a completely different array.  That is, you're setting values in one array, but looking for them somewhere different.  This is never going to work.

Comment: So which one should I keep the String or the int array?

Comment: Well, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: I changed all of them to String's removing the array of int and it still doesn't work... nothing gets dropped just the JOption pane's show up saying red and yellow has both won whenever you try and click drop.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others are saying, your for loop seems to have a bug in it:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    for(int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
        if(/* condition */) {
            return true;
        } else if(/* condition */) {
            return true;
        } else if(/* condition */) {
            return true;

        } else {            // bug
            return false;   // here
        }
    }
}

return false;
```

This will only check the very first iteration so you need to remove the else.

It also seems you don't check the result of winCheck:

```
winCheck(firstColour);
displayWinner(firstColour);
```

And I think you mean something like this:

```
if(winCheck(firstColour)) {
    displayWinner(firstColour);
}
```

Comment: Don't you want it to return false if everything else is not true though?

Comment: You already do that when the loop ends. Returning false inside the loop will only check the first spot on the board it finds. Removing the else will check the entire board before returning false.

Comment: Okay I fixed that up, but It still doesn't tell you when you won?

Comment: I revised my program, could you run it and tell me why it doesn't pick up on the winning conditions please?

Comment: Make sure you've updated to evaluating with equals everywhere. Otherwise not sure. There could be other bugs we didn't find.

Comment: I have no clue. Could it be someplace in my winning conditions and my drop circle subroutines?

Comment: I changed everything to a string and to a .equals but this line doesn't work now:         if (spotOnBoard[row][n]>0) break;

Comment: Please see the revised edition, you'll notice you'll get an error when you run compile it.

Comment: In your revised version - what do you think this line `spotOnBoard[--row][n].equals(firstColour);`, in the middle of `dropCircle`, is doing?

Comment: Yes, as @DavidWallace is pointing out, in the process of changing to equals you've changed some lines that should be assignments. Remember `=` (assigns a value to a variable) is not the same thing as `==` (compares the values of two variables).

Comment: I'm getting a null pointer exception on this line:         spotOnBoard[row][col].equals(blank); < why?

Comment: Because you haven't assigned anything to `spotOnBoard[row][col]` yet.

Comment: What do I assign it to?

Comment: spotOnBoard[row][col]=blank; when I changed it to this it doesn't work because spot on board is an array of strings and blank is an integer value.

Comment: All of your static int's declared for possible board contents need to be redeclared as Strings, if you plan to keep the spotOnBoard array as a String type. Personally, I would strongly consider an enum type to accomplish this, or revert the spotOnBoard and all subsequent logic/assignments to int.

Comment: I changed everything to int, could you please review my edited version and let me know why it still doesn't show the winning conditions?

Answer (score 0):

The answers are likely going to change as you make revisions to your program, but you seem to be missing the core concepts of how to use the arrays you've defined for your game.

Strings, ints, booleans, doubles, etc. whatever Objects/primitives you decide to use to model your game, you should be using consistently across the program. (ie: Strings should be compared using .equals() as has been mentioned numerous times) and the data structures you've provided should serve a meaningful purpose as well (ie: don't assign a new data structure for use in one place and assign another of similar purpose in another place if you can legitimately share the same data in both places).

As of now, it looks like you have a bit of a problem in your dropCircle method.

```
public void dropCircle(int n) {
  if (endOfGame) return;
  gameStart=true;
  int row;
  for (row=0; row<maxRow; row++)
    if (spotOnBoard[row][n]>0) break;  
  if (row>0) {
    if(winCheck(firstColour)){            // checking for a win here will result in
                                          // false because the winning position has
                                          // yet to be assigned.
      displayWinner(firstColour);
    }
    spotOnBoard[--row][n] = firstcolour;  // move this line above the if statement above.
    if (firstColour==red)
      firstColour=yellow;
    else
      firstColour=red;        
  }
  drawConnectFourBoard.repaint();
}
```

Another point to note is your consistent use of Strings and ints to represent board state. You can conceivably implement this whole game using the same data type, and it would eliminate a good deal of your logic errors, which are most likely being caused by poor handling of data types.

One thing I might suggest, is you rename and consolidate some of your data structures.
spotOnBoard implies a single space on the board, when in fact, this array *is* your board. The spot on the board, is the element at [row,col]

Second, I would look at the javadocs for Object equals. Specifically String equals.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Good luck

Edit: Revised to reflect OP updates and suggested actions to take.

Comment: so in drop circle should I remove this line: if (spotOnBoard[row][n]>0) break; and what's the second line doing that you pointed out?

Comment: The conversation being had in the other answer's comments is what that line is doing. As it's written, you are comparing the contents of an element in a 2D array of Strings (of type String, naturally) to an int. It's not an assignment statement. I don't know what the first if statement is checking for, but you would want to perform the same comparison you were using with ints, but for Strings.

Comment: Please review edited version because it still doesn't work properly.

Comment: @user3216679 - It seems to me that you are making many quite elementary mistakes, and asking some very basic questions.  I don't mean to sound patronising, but my honest opinion is that you should start with an easier project than this one, and return to this project once you have mastered more of the basics of Java.

Comment: I honestly have no choice but to finish this program. I'm so close it's just the winning that I'm stuck on.

Comment: Look at the first sentence of this answer - "... you seem to be missing the core concepts of how to use the arrays you've defined ...".  I would have to concur.  I don't feel you're quite as close as you think you are.

Comment: For what it's worth, why you're not getting the results you want is because you're checking for a win condition before you've assigned the value of the piece currently being dropped to the board. When you run through winCheck on the drop of the 4th piece, it's not actually assigned to the spotOnBoard array, and you're getting a return of false. The last value to achieve a win is then assigned and you then resume play, thinking you've done something wrong. When you attempt to drop the *fifth* piece, that's when it says you win. Move the winCheck call in dropCircle to *after* the assignment.

Comment: Yes, you need to switch your statements so that the move is made before the win is checked. Right now you will notice that the win *will* be found on the next move if you make another.